# TF31001: Cannot connect to TFS - System.ServiceModel.Internals failed to load

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

Visual Studio 2013 Update 1: everything was working just fine, and was successfully connected to TFS server.  After I ran Repair on VS2013 I cannot connect to TFS and getting the following error.

### Could Not Load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have re-registered .NET 4 and 2, restarted IIS and re-applied Update 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to Repair .NET 4.5.1 installation and everything started working after the reboot.